# Unset array field if it is empty after pull in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

How to unset field(array) if its length after `$pull` operation equals 0 in MongoDB?

I need to do it using only 1 query. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in a regular update query, but You can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

Consider this is a sample document and you want to pull "1" from `array` field:

```
{
  "array": [1]
}
```

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `array` and filter array that is not equal to "1"
- `$cond` to check after pull, is `array` field empty then remove by `$$REMOVE` otherwise nothing to do

```
db.collection.update(
  { "array": 1 },
  [{
    $set: {
      array: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$array",
          cond: { $ne: ["$$this", 1] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      array: {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: ["$array", []] },
          "$$REMOVE",
          "$array"
        ]
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/alv2uyMl4fe)

---

The second alternate option,

- `$cond` to check is `array` equal to the single element that we are going to pull `[1]` then remove `array` field otherwise go to `$filter` operation to remove single element

```
db.collection.update(
  { "array": 1 },
  [{
    $set: {
      array: {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: ["$array", [1]] },
          "$$REMOVE",
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$array",
              cond: { $ne: ["$$this",1] }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7fbvBVs0KIL)